# Total number of answers should not reflect the deleted ones

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-answers

After some answers are deleted (and show up as gray shaded in users with enough reputations), the total numbers of answers shown on the question page still includes those that are deleted. For example, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020851/what-is-the-name-of-the-method-for-hash) at the moment has two remaining answers and two deleted answers, and the total still says four. This is strange. I think it should reflect and subtract the deleted answers.

Comment: For me it says 2, could it be caching? Or perhaps because you are>10k on SO

Comment: Says 2 for me.  I am pretty sure it changes based on visible questions for the specific user.

Comment: I think the total reflects how many answers you can see. Someone under 10k reputation should only see two answers, so their total should be 2.

Comment: I know that it shows different numbers depending on whether you can see it. I am not claiming that this is a bug. I believe this is an intended feature, and I am claiming that that is strange. This is a feature request, not a bug report.

Comment: It makes sense to me. I think it would be stranger to see "2 Answers" when it shows me four.

Comment: @Geobits My interpretation is that the deleted answers are gone in the normal sense, but are peekable as if you are looking at the edit history. They are closer to being gone rather than exsiting.

Comment: I get what you're saying, I just disagree ;)